# How to access, edit or delete tokens in stringtokenizer in java

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

Its my first question on stackoverflow please cooperate

How to read tokens one by one using a loop???
i have too many tokens in my stringtokenizer and i want to analyze them one by one using a loop(for or while any one) so please me help in this.
Please tell me other better methods to analyze large number of strings

Comment: Post what you tried??

Comment: you didn't searched before posting question, there is too much docs related to this question on internet for example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/

Comment: i just made tokens and made a string to read token using .nexttoken() but now i dont know how to access the next one and all  others

Comment: *"Its my first question on stackoverflow please cooperate"*.  Here's some free advice.  In future, you should choose your words more carefully.  What you have written ("please cooperate") is the kind of thing that a parent or teacher would say to an unruly child.  If you want people to help you, it would be wise to be more respectful.

Comment: sorry stephen i ll take care of it in future thanx for advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick Google search yields this code sample.

```
String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by mkyong";
System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
  System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
}
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-stringtokenizer-example/